# Jquery datepicker From - To fields with disabled days

Tags: jquery, datepicker, dependencies, field

I have 2 input fields with datepicker:

```
    $('#dpd1').datepicker();
    $('#dpd2').datepicker();
```

Is it possible to make second field depended on first field?

For example i wont to pick date '2018-01-15' in first field, than hide datepicker calendar, focus on second field where should be enabled only days from first field + 1 day ('2018-01-16' and higher).

I found this script:

```
if(jQuery('#dpd1').length){
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
    var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    checkout.setValue(newDate);
  }
  checkin.hide();
  $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
  }
```

But i am not able to customize this script for my purpose. Is any one here who can help me? Thx.

Comment: I don't know if you are using, or planning on using Bootstrap in your project, but there's a component called Bootstrap-datetimepicker that's excellent for date/time selection and it has the very same functionality you're looking for. It's built in, almost no code is needed, just configuration. You can find it here: [Bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Of course, it uses JQuery as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
if(jQuery('#dpd1').length){

var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({

}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {

    var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    checkout.setValue(newDate);

  checkin.hide();
  $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
}
```